# how to find and Update record on Parse.com

Tags: c#, winforms, parse-platform

I'm working on c# winforms Application. I want to find and Update any specific record on parse.com.

My problem is that I find the record but I don't know how to update it.

The find code is this:

```
   int ID = Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text);
   var FindID = (from find in ParseObject.GetQuery("DriverID")
                   where find.Get<Int32>("DriverID") == ID
                    select find);
   var ID = FindID.FindAsync();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally its working

```
public async void UpdateDriverOnParse(Int32 ID)
        {


            var query = (from find in ParseObject.GetQuery("DriverLogin")
                         where find.Get<Int32>("SystemID") == ID
                         select find);

            // Retrieve the results
            IEnumerable<ParseObject> Data = await query.FindAsync();

            //for updating the selected row
            foreach (var row in Data)
            {

                row["Pin"] = Convert.ToInt32(txtPinNo.Text);
                row["DriverID"] = Convert.ToInt32(txtCallSign.Text);
                row["Name"] = txtFirstName.Text+" "+txtMname.Text+" "+txtLastName.Text;
                await row.SaveAsync();

            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FindAsync returns an IEnumerable. If you just want one object you can use FirstAsync. When you have your object, update it like you would any IDictionary and then call 'await ID.SaveAsync()'